# Nested subquery giving eror of unknown column

Tags: mysql

I am facing uknown column 'id' issue which is exist in db_emp.test_etl. Then also it is giving uknown column error why?.This query successfully working in mysql version 8.0.14 but not mysql version 8.0.11.

```
18:30:48    
update db_emp.test_etl 
   set name='abc' 
 where id in( select max(SETNO) 
                from ( select sum(SETNO) 
                         from AUC1 
                        where SETNO=id
                     ) a
            )   
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' 0.0024 sec
```

> db_emp.test_etl table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE `test_etl` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

> Above query work for single level sub query as below :

```
12:02:57
update capitalmarket.test_etl 
   set name='abc' 
 where id in(select sum(SETTLEMENTNO) 
               from capitalmarket.AUCTION 
              where SETTLEMENTNO=id
            )
0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0  0.0020 sec
```

Comment: Do you have `id` in the table `AUC1`? Can you post your `AUC1` table as well?

Comment: You do know that you have `SETNO` in your first subquery and `SETTLEMENTNO` in the second? And show us the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE test_etl;`.

Comment: It is unclear what the UPDATE is supposed to do. Please explain so we can help you rewrite it. Nested subquueries in MySQL have limitations, so you'll need to remove the double nesting..

Answer (score 1):

The problem here must be with the `id` reference in the innermost `SELECT`. For a long time MySQL has had trouble with resolving outer references in correlated subqueries if those references were placed inside *derived tables* in the correlated subqueries.

Apparently the problem has been [resolved in 8.0.14](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-14.html):

> #### Optimizer Notes
>
> - Previously, derived tables and common table expressions could not contain outer references. Outer references are now permitted.

If you want the query to compile both in 8.0.14 and in 8.0.11, apparently you need to rewrite it to somehow avoid referencing the `id` column in a derived table. Before making any suggestions, I must note that your example has other issues than the unresolved `id` reference. The very first line in this correlated subquery:

```
select max(SETNO)
from ( select sum(SETNO) 
       from AUC1 
       where SETNO=id
     ) a
```

already has a problem, because it references an unknown column `SETNO`. The derived table `a` does not have such a column.

So, for the sake of showing how to resolve the `id` reference issue, I am going to assume that `sum(SETNO)` was meant to be written as `sum(SETNO) AS SETNO`. That way at least<sup>*</sup> the outer level `SETNO` reference becomes valid.

Basically, the solution is to get the `MAX(SETNO)` in an alternative way, such that a derived table is actually not needed at all and thus the `id` column can be referenced directly in the correlated subquery. For that you will use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1`. Specifically, you rewrite your correlated subquery as follows:

```
SELECT sum(SETNO)
FROM AUC1
WHERE SETNO = id
ORDER BY sum(SETNO) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This way the correlated subquery is still getting the same value but no longer references outer columns from a derived table.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>The query still does not make much sense as it is, though. But at least it should compile now and allow us to demonstrate the solution.</sub>